# What solutions do I have to enforce memory limit on PHP server?

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I would like to enforce memory limit on a folder basis (and have it applied on subfolders) but I don't want the user able to change the memory limit.

I know I can disable `ini_set` and I know I can enforce a hard limit or deny `ini_set` with Suhosin.

With the first one, I doubt it will block changing it from the `user.ini` file, for the second, the user may still be able to change it to the hard limit I enforce with Suhosin.

In both cases, I would prefer to not entierly block `ini_set` because it may have a legit use for other settings.

In case it is important, I'm using PHP version 5.4.4 with nginx (PHP in FPM mode)

Comment: Why do you want to limit by folder? That's a little strange. Generally you would want to limit by user, or perhaps user/domain.

Comment: Because i prefer solutions that may work on multiple setup and i'm not sure limiting by user would work if i try to reproduce it with something else than nginx+php (be it apache+php or IIS+php), if you can tell me more about a per user solution it may end up good as well.